# Does $\sum_{1\leq n} \mathbb P(A_n)=\infty$ in this case?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb P(A_n)=0$ and $\sum_{1\leq n} \mathbb P(A_n-A_{n+1})<\infty$. I wonder if  $$\sum_{1\leq n} \mathbb P(A_n)<\infty$$

I tried the following.

$\sum_{1\leq n} \mathbb P(A_n-A_{n+1})=\sum_{1\leq n} \mathbb P(A_n)-\mathbb P(A_n\bigcap A_{n+1})$.If we can show $\sum_{1\leq n}\mathbb P(A_n\bigcap A_{n+1})<0$ we are done. However I don't think  $\sum_{1\leq n}\mathbb P(A_n\bigcap A_{n+1})<\infty$ always  holds, because the only control $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb P(A_n)=0$ has on  $\mathbb P (A_n\bigcap A_{n+1})$ is  $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb P (A_n\bigcap A_{n+1})=0$ but this is not sufficient for the seires to converge. Any comment and answer are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false. Let $U$ be a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$ and $A_n=\{U<1/n\}$. $P(A_n-A_{n+1})=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$, which will converge when summed. However $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)=\infty$.